# Get the name attribute of a GenericForeign key object

Tags: django, django-models, django-contenttypes, generic-foreign-key

I have the following model in a Django app:
How can I get the "name" attribute of any selected content_object in this model and display it in  list_display of the modelAdmin class, instead of just displaying the keys of the GenericForeign Key objects. Please I really need help with this.

```
class Checkout(models.Model):
    checkout_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    check_in_complete = models.BooleanField(default=False, editable=False)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType,
                                     limit_choices_to={"model__in": ('Facilitator', 'Enumerator', 'Tutor')})
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name='Receiver')
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

Comment: Did you try `my_checkout.content_object.name`?

Answer (score 0):

Since `GenericForeignKey` is not a normal field object, you can not use it in filters:

```
Checkout.objects.filter(content_object=other_obj) # this will fail
```

But if you want to access the `name` property of the object your checkout is associated with using `GenericForeignKey` you can do it like following:

```
name = checkout_obj.content_object.name
```

Comment: obj.content_object works fine. Please confirm on your end.  
 Checkout.objects.filter(content_object=other_obj) will fail as you said

Comment: Thanks, you are right!. I updated my answer. I got confused with it not working in filters. It does work directly on an object.